# Ubuntu Maverick install of ros-electric-pr2-desktop

Tags: ubuntu, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install electric pr2 desktop on ubuntu maverick (10.10) following the instructions at http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/PR2/electric, which tells me to install the package *ros-electric-pr2-desktop*, only apt tells me that package doesn't exist. Why not?

I believe I have apt sources setup ok, using *'deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu maverick main'* and can see plenty of of other ros-electric packages, just not the desktop one, [maverick is missing](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-electric-pr2-desktop/).

This is similar to question [ubuntu-install-of-electric-pr2-desktop](http://answers.ros.org/question/11881/ubuntu-install-of-electric-pr2-desktop), except that question and answer is for Oneric.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28101/ubuntu-maverick-install-of-ros-electric-pr2-desktop/) by [markpitchless](https://answers.ros.org/users/1668/markpitchless/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

pr2-desktop is not available on Maverick as some of the required packages do not build on that platform.  As Maverick is due to be EOL in a month, it is unlikely this will be fixed.  You will need to update to Natty or Oneiric if you wish to use the full suite, or install pr2 stacks individually.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0